# How to test the normality of many variables in R at the same time?

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I have a data frame that is consisted of 20 observations and 35 variables.

The normality test for one variable will be

```
shapiro.test(mydata$var1)
```

I want to test the normality for all variables at the same time. How can I do this in R?

Comment: `sapply(mydata, shapiro.test)`

Comment: How do you want it to output?

Comment: @jeremycg your solution doesn't control for the familywise error rate, which is likely very important here

Comment: @Carl I want the output in a form of dataframe

Comment: Right, but like do you want a new column for each test, or a new row for each test. Can you edit your question to give the structure of the output you want?

Comment: @Carl Thanks. the output of Alex's code below works fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends a lot on what kind of output you're looking for and what you wish to do to control the familywise error rate. Here's one solution using Bonferroni corrections

```
# example data
t <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(700), 20,35))

shapiro_test_df <- function(df, bonf= TRUE, alpha= 0.05) {
  l <- lapply(df, shapiro.test)
  s <- do.call("c", lapply(l, "[[", 1))
  p <- do.call("c", lapply(l, "[[", 2))
  if (bonf == TRUE) {
    sig <- ifelse(p > alpha / length(l), "H0", "Ha")
  } else {
    sig <- ifelse(p > alpha, "H0", "Ha")
  }
  return(list(statistic= s,
              p.value= p,
              significance= sig,
              method= ifelse(bonf == TRUE, "Shapiro-Wilks test with Bonferroni Correction",
                             "Shapiro-Wilks test without Bonferroni Correction")))
}

shapiro_test_df(t)
```

Comment: is it possible to add in your loop ifelse to log-transform variables that are not normally distributed